# Difference of "Use of Stack Memory After Return" between native arm64 and native Intel/rosetta2 x86_64

Tags: xcode, clang, x86-64, cpu-architecture, arm64

I have an odd message using my code base (C/C++ & Swift).
The code itself is way too big to post, but I wanted to hear what people think could be the reason.

I run the same code natively on my M1 Apple Silicon chip without any issues. I have all diagnostics turned on:
[image]

The fun begins when I use it on an Intel based Mac and/or under Rosetta2. (All systems are Big Sur).

```
Vithanco(83162,0x20400de00) malloc: enabling scribbling to detect mods to free blocks
Vithanco(83162,0x20400de00) malloc: nano zone abandoned due to inability to preallocate reserved vm space.
applicationDidFinishLaunching
objc[83162]: Class _NSZombie_NSSimpleRegularExpressionCheckingResult is implemented in both ?? (0x60400017ab90) and ?? (0x60400016ffd0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
=================================================================
==83162==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: stack-use-after-return on address 0x0001105fee00 at pc 0x000101fbd30f bp 0x000308d4eb70 sp 0x000308d4eb68
WRITE of size 8 at 0x0001105fee00 thread T0
==83162==WARNING: invalid path to external symbolizer!
==83162==WARNING: Failed to use and restart external symbolizer!
    #0 0x101fbd30e in textfont_dict_open+0x44e (/Users/(deleted)/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/...-gwcenzuufsseezetprookmoioioy/Build/Products/Debug/.../Contents/MacOS/Vithanco:x86_64+0x1012b630e)
    #1 0x1026f3036 in loadGraphvizLibraries+0x156 (/Users/(deleted)/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Vithanco-gwcenzuufsseezetprookmoioioy/Build/Products/Debug/Vithanco.app/Contents/MacOS/Vithanco:x86_64+0x1019ec036)
    #2 0x1026f618c in globalinit_33_2FCABEB9B9698DE37811B48DE0525A0F_func0+0xc (/Users/(deleted)/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Vithanco-gwcenzuufsseezetprookmoioioy/Build/Products/Debug/Vithanco.app/Contents/MacOS/Vithanco:x86_64+0x1019ef18c)
    #3 0x1102400af in _dispatch_client_callout+0x7 (/usr/lib/system/introspection/libdispatch.dylib:x86_64+0x40af)
```

There is a lot more to come on the error stack, but not much of use.

I was just wondering: what could be the case? Why would the same code run into a `Use of Stack Memory After Return` only on one architecture? Same code was running previously on Intel. So, would this be a macOS, compiler issue or something else?

Comment: Possibly it's a real bug in your code, but perhaps differences in optimization choices when compiling for different ISAs might have led to an actual symptom no happening, or it not being *detected* because it's in a different place relative to the stack frame.  I don't know what that sanitizer actually does to detect problems so IDK what it might miss.

Comment: It is important to recognize that sanitizers, test cases, etc... attempt to uncover the source of bugs, but their inability to uncover bugs does not imply an absence of bugs.   Somewhere, you are returning a reference to a stack based object.

Comment: I forgot to say that the App does crash always on x86_64 architecture and has no problems on arm64 - without any analysers.

Comment: You hopefully already realize this, but happening to work is one possible behaviour for C and C++ undefined behaviour, so doesn't rule out bugs.  It's also likely to be correlated with analyzers not detecting problems.

Comment: fully understood! Indeed, the problem existed, but it didn't affect one architecture. I was indeed just looking for a way forward to identify the issue. I am happy to find the error in my code. That made it easy to fix :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used this declaration:

```
extern struct _dt_s textfont_dict_open(GVC_t * gvc);
```

instead of

```
extern struct _dt_s * textfont_dict_open(GVC_t * gvc);
```

Interesting, how the two architectures led to a very different outcome although I never used the outcome of the method.

Comment: Returning a large struct by value is apparently done differently in the different calling conventions.  In x86-64 System V, if it's larger than 16 bytes the caller makes space for the return-value object and passes a pointer as if it were a hidden first arg, displacing all the other args.  So the callee will be treating that uninitialized return-value object as the `GVC_t * gvc` declared arg, if the definition is just returning a pointer which fits in the RAX register.

Comment: But apparently the AArch64 calling convention uses a different register for a return-value pointer when one is needed, leaving the explicit args in the same registers, starting with `x0`.  https://godbolt.org/z/YG6hdj.  So the function got a return-value object in a register but would never look at it, harmlessly ignoring that mismatch between declaration and definition as long as you never try to use the return value.